# Rutherford scattering in Quantum Mechanics terms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, scattering

[Rutherford scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutherford_scattering) stands as the first evidence of atoms having the positive charge concentrated in a small nucleus.

While the classical description of the phenomenon is satisfactory, it puzzles me that no description from Quantum Mechanics point of view appears to exist.

Is there any? Or could someone elaborate one? At least the starting points maybe, no need for a fully coherent deduction although it would be very welcome.

Comment: Much of the fields of nuclear physics and particle physics are devoted to the studies of these scattering processes. While nuclear physics can afford to take a more classical or at least semi-classical view of some of these processes, in particle physics these collisions are being described mostly by quantum field theoretical methods. The most simple (and that's bit of a euphemism) aspect is probably that of electromagnetic scattering as describe by quantum electrodynamics (QED).

Comment: Nuclear physics has little to say of this type of scattering, as long as energies are as low and no internal excitations of nuclei occur. Although I agree that QED might be the more correct choice as approach, I would be happy with a Classical QM formulation.

Comment: That's why it's being described with classical electromagnetism for low energies, which is good enough. Once that fails, one has to either use ad-hoc models as in nuclear physics or pull the entire apparatus of quantum field theory out of the hat, which won't work well to begin with for alpha on heavy nuclei scattering because that's really a many-particle system. The more interesting case for the application of exact theoretical models is that of the standard model which deals with few-particle collisions.

Comment: I don't actually understand what you mean by *"no description from Quantum Mechanics point of view appears to exist."* Most (or at least many) quantum texts do this.

Comment: I had not seen a specific treatment of this problem. I have found it now in page 477 of A. S. Davydov's Quantum Mechanics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rutherford scattering is simply elastic scattering in a Coulomb potential. This process can, of course, be treated quantum mechanically, and this is described in any QM text book that covers scattering theory.

There is a strange accident which is that the differential cross section computed classically agrees exactly with the quantum mechanical results. This is ultimately broken by relativistic corrections, higher order QED effects etc, but the leading 1/$\sin(\theta/2)^4$ is the same classically and quantum mechanically.  Of course, Rutherford had no way to know this, so he got a little lucky with his classical formula.

Answer (score 1):

Rutherford scattering is electric at energies lower than 28 MeV, the alpha particle total binding energy. The alpha particles are destroyed, freeing the magnetic moments of the nucleons. Therefore the not so anomalous is magnetic as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Also can you provide a reference to your image?

Comment: do you have some reference?